# What does offset mean in a pandas rolling window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

The rolling window function [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) takes a `window` argument that is described as follows:

> **window** : int, or offset
>
> Size of the moving window. This is the number of observations used for
> calculating the statistic. Each window will be a fixed size.
>
> If its an offset then this will be the time period of each window.
> Each window will be a variable sized based on the observations
> included in the time-period. This is only valid for datetimelike
> indexes. This is new in 0.19.0

What actually is an *offset* in this context?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a nutshell, if you use an `offset` like "2D" (2 days), pandas will use the datetime info in the index (if available), potentially accounting for any missing rows or irregular frequencies.  But if you use a simple `int` like 2, then pandas will treat the index as a simple integer index [0,1,2,...] and ignore any datetime info in the index.

A simple example should make this clear:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':range(4)}, 
    index=pd.to_datetime(['1-1-2018','1-2-2018','1-4-2018','1-5-2018']))

            x
2018-01-01  0
2018-01-02  1
2018-01-04  2
2018-01-05  3
```

Note that (1) the index is a datetime, but also (2) it is missing '2018-01-03'.  So if you use a plain integer like 2, `rolling` will just look at the last two rows, regardless of the datetime value (in a sense it's behaving like `iloc[i-1:i]` where `i` is the current row):

```
df.rolling(2).count()

              x
2018-01-01  1.0
2018-01-02  2.0
2018-01-04  2.0
2018-01-05  2.0
```

Conversely, if you use an offset of 2 days (`'2D'`), `rolling` will use the actual datetime values and accounts for any irregularities in the datetime index.

```
df.rolling('2D').count()

              x
2018-01-01  1.0
2018-01-02  2.0
2018-01-04  1.0
2018-01-05  2.0
```

Also note, you need the index to be sorted in ascending order when using a date offset, but it doesn't matter when using a simple integer (since you're just ignoring the index anyway).

Comment: to give offset in mircroseconds (say10), what string will be used?, I tried '10f', didn't work

Comment: @Legolas  this info is surprisingly hard to find altho guessing often works well in this situation ;-)  I would use 'us' but 'micro' or 'microseconds' should work too.  See here for more:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas.Timedelta

Comment: @JohnE That doc doesn't mention lower-case `d` like in the example, only `days`. But only `2d` seems to work, while `2days` doesn't (?).

Comment: @thakis  Thanks for noting this. I'm not really sure why "days" doesn't work here.  In other cases you can specify the offset for days in those other ways (e.g. try `pd.Timedelta('2days')`) but I also can't get "days" to work here. FWIW, I think that 'D' is probably the most standard or canonical way to specify "days" here so I changed the example above to use `2D` instead of `2d`

Comment: @thakis  This is a little silly, probably, but if you really wanted to use "days" for some reason, you could do it like this, by explicitly converting to a timedelta:  `df.rolling(pd.Timedelta('2days')).count()`

Comment: For a list of accepted date offsets see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Answer (score 1):

Offsets can be either `offset` (strings) or `pd.Timedelta` objects. Internally, both of them get converted into an offset using `pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset()` method.

The basic implementation of a rolling window computation with an offset is that  for any given index, the offset is subtracted from it creating a slice of the column, i.e. a window, and the function (e.g. `max()` below) is called on this window. By default, first point in the window edge is excluded from the computation.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,4,3,2]}, 
                  index=pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-04']))

df['A'].rolling('2D').max()

2020-01-01    1.0
2020-01-02    4.0
2020-01-02    4.0
2020-01-04    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

In the example above, the calculations are made in the following windows:

```
2020-01-01               = max(1)          # `min_periods=1` on time-series
[2020-01-01, 2020-01-02] = max(1, 4)       # only the first value on 2020-01-02 is considered because the second is not seen yet
[2020-01-01, 2020-01-02] = max(1, 4, 3)
[2020-01-03, 2020-01-04] = max(2)          # there is no data on 2020-01-03
```

---

All possible offsets are in the `pd.offsets` module. Among those, only the ones with fixed frequency are valid offsets.<sup>1</sup> They are:

- `Day` (`D`)
- `Hour` (`H`)
- `Minute` (`T`)
- `Second` (`S`)
- `Milli` (`L`)
- `Micro` (`U`)
- `Nano` (`N`)

Also the index can be `DatetimeIndex`, `TimedeltaIndex` or `PeriodIndex`. In fact, the rolling window don't even have to be on the index; it can be on a column of `datetime`, `timedelta` or `period` dtype.

So for example, to use a rolling window of 3 microseconds, use `3U`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.date_range('2020-01-01 12:00:00', '2020-01-01 12:00:01', 10**6), 
    'value': 1}).head()
# check that each step is indeed 1 microsecond
df['time'].diff().dropna().dt.microseconds.eq(1).all()   # True

df.rolling('3U', on='time')['value'].sum()

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The following code returns these offsets.

```py
offsets = {
    name: obj().name for name in dir(pd.offsets) 
    if hasattr((obj:=getattr(pd.offsets, name)), '_nanos_inc')
}
```