# pandas rolling window: variable length from start to x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas-dataframe-rolling) window I can set a `window` size that describes a fixed width (fixed *number of elements* or fixed [*offset*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855400/pandas-rolling-window-what-does-offset-mean)).

How can I get a window that always begins at the first entry and rolls forward to each entry? For example having a series `x` in the DataFrame, I want to get the following windows per row:

```
    x    intended_window
0  10    [10]
1  11    [10,11]
2  12    [10,11,12]
3  13    [10,11,12,13]
4  14    [10,11,12,13,14]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate result—you can compute this directly using pandas' expanding mean. Pandas provides a feature called an [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) window, which lets you perform computations on expanding windows of values. For your case, you'll want `expanding.mean`:

```
df.x.expanding().mean()

0    10.0
1    10.5
2    11.0
3    11.5
4    12.0
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Note it is the same as what you're currently using:

```
df['intended_window'].apply(np.mean)

0    10.0
1    10.5
2    11.0
3    11.5
4    12.0
Name: intended_window, dtype: float64
```

But the former is SO much more performant.

Comment: I don't think that's a window (from [`pandas.core.window`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#window)), or is it? I can't apply window-functions to it. `type (df['intended_window'])` returns `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: @ascripter Each row is a window of values from `x`. You can use `apply`/`applymap` on each row in isolation. Is this not what was required? Your question seemed to indicate this :)

Comment: I was thinking about doing sth. like `df['x'].rolling().mean()`, but this doesn't work. I just figured it out this way: `df['window'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))`. Not that nice, but works :)

Comment: @ascripter wow, this is the very definition of an XY problem. Use `df.x.expanding().mean()` and you get the exact same thing. I bet that's what you want.